# The stings of my cactus look weird with a weird shading but only in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, blenderkit

Why do they have those black noisy spots ? I have created a vertex group from the cactus vertices and assigned a particle system to those. For the particle System i have created a little cone that i have used as the reference object. Can anyone help me :)

[image]

This is how it looks in EVEE
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you have overlapping faces which creates the Z-Fighting effect, to fix that select your particle object, switch to Edit mode and try a M > Merge by Distance

Comment: Hey thank u! is there a way to only select the particle System? Seems like i can only select the object with the particle system, or did u mean this ?

Comment: I'm talking about the cone you've created and that you use as particle

Comment: Hmm nah i just did it nothing has changed :(

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ..or, at least, give us a shot of your shader-tree.. there might be something in there EEVEE doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a displacement texture anywhere on the stings? If so, reduce the displacement node influence (or delete displacement node).

Comment: Hello please don't use the Your Answer field to ask a question or to comment, instead yse the Add a comment button